# Find coordinates of parallel lines within a circle sector

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Geometry is not my strongest subject and I can't find solution to my problem.

I'm writing algorithm that finds coordinates in a circle sector. There is $n$ amount of parallel lines, each with equal distance from each other, within circle sector. Below I attach image for reference:

[Reference image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6hRd.png)

Problem: Find coordinates of $(x_n,y_n)$ and $(p_n,q_n)$

Known variables:

$P$ - point (0, 0). Point P is the origin of the circle

$\alpha$ - triangle angle

$d$ - distance between parallel lines

$r$ - circle radius

So far I found formula for $x_n$ and $y_n$:

Values for $x_n$:

1. $x_1$ = $\frac{d}{sin\alpha}$
2. $x_n = n*x_1$

Values for $y_n$:

$y_n = 0$

I don't know how to find coordinates of $(p_n, q_n)$. I've been trying to solve this for a few hours now and I still can't find solution. Thank you in advance!

**PS:**
Solidworks is only software that know how to use to show geometry. I don't know how to use interactive geometry software. Sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: I don't understand that request for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is easier if you rotate the figure so that the oblique radius becomes horizontal. Then you intersect the circle of equation

$$u^2+v^2=r^2$$

with the horizontals

$$v_k=-kd.$$

The intersection points are thus

$$\left(\sqrt{r^2-v_k^2},v_k\right).$$

Now you can rotate to bring the figure back in the original position. It is convenient to use complex numbers and compute

$$p_k+iq_k=(u_k+iv_k)(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha).$$

[image]

The $(x_k,y_k)$ are easier.

Comment: Yes it is definitely easier to first solve this and then do the axes rotation. I solved the original one and that really looks more complex due to all the $sin \alpha$ and $tan \alpha$.